# How can I rewrite an old URL using variables to a static html page?

Tags: seo, htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect old URLS to the new URLS, the old site used variables in the URL but the new site uses SEO friendly URLs.

When I try to redirect the old URL, it is not redirecting correctly and I get 404 errors. I am unsure if the SEO rewrite is the cause of the other rewrite condition failing.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com    
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] RewriteRule ^(.+).html index.php?seo_title=$1 [nc]    
Redirect 301 /WEBPAGE http://www.example.com/WEBPAGE.html    
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.co.uk/test/test.php?c=viewtest&id=56&sat=9&mainsat=1&start=0$ http://www.example.com/NEW_URL.html
ErrorDocument 404 /PAGE_NOT_FOUND.html
```

**Question:** How can I write the RewriteRule so that it redirects the old URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I found was that the URL is split between the file and the variables as would be expected.

So everything after the `?` is taken as a query string.

You need to add a condition to check the query string (you can include Regular Expressions)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^viewtest&id=56&sat=9&mainsat=1&start=0$  
RewriteRule ^/test/test.php$ http://www.example.com/WEBPAGE.html? [R=301,L]
```

Also, notice the `?` after the redirected URL, this stops the variables being appended to the new URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript redirect on particular pages, If possible in your case.

Comment: That's not a good idea. If you want a redirect page instead of a transparent redirect, it's best to use the `META REFRESH` tag. That doesn't rely on JS (which web crawlers don't follow). But it's still best to use 301 if you want to transfer PageRank.

Comment: not possible the pages were dynamically generated from an older system that is no longer in use

Comment: @Craig: i hope you already had tried HTML redirect, JS redirect and .htaccess redirect. right?